Use of the word "linear"
Where was the word "linear" first used in terms like "linear function" or "linear equation" and what was the reason behind this name?

You can find such information on MacTutor.  Both usages date from the early 19th century.

I figure "linear functions" like $y=mx+b$ were so called because their graphs are lines

Straight lines...

The Online Etymology Dictionary shows that 'linear' was in use from the 1640s. In context, Google NGram Viewer shows that 'linear function' and 'linear equation' were in use from the early 1800s and peaked in the 1960s.

Thanks all for useful answers!

The Online Etymology Dictionary & Google NGram Viewer are very helpful, but they consider only modern languages. I think, the answer is in Latin texts. Are there so powerful resourses like Etymology Dictionary & NGram Viewer in Latin?
